# Make it possible to view the review answer on the same page as other answers in answer queues

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, late-answers, first-answers, low-quality-answers

Quite often, I leave a comment on new answers if they add nothing to existing answers. Sometimes I also downvote because of this. I also think this is a quite important thing to do when reviewing.

But this can be quite tedious to do, because to compare, you need to go back and forth between the tabs "Answer" and "Other answers". The solution I'm currently using is to open a new window so that I can have both the review answer and another answer on the screen at the same time.

I suggest the possibility to view them side by side. Or the review answer above the others, but always in view when scrolling through the others. I'm not a UI guy, so I leave the exact details to someone who knows better.

This also applies to the case when looking at the "Question" tab to see if the answer really answers the question, but in this case, I don't find it equally important, but maybe it could be solved at the same time.

EDIT:

As mentioned in comments, this also applies to the late answer queue and the low quality answer queue. Thanks @Elikill58 and @Tomerikoo

Comment: I agree. It's mostly important with "Late answer" review queue by checking for duplicates

Comment: I love this request. I also usually open the question in a new tab, put the review and the question tabs in a vertical split view and compare them. Having that as part of the UI in a single page will be quite awesome! Could you make the request more general for all review queues? i.e. applies to First Answers, Late Answers and Low Quality Answers

Comment: @Tomerikoo Maybe I rolled back prematurely. I had not even seen your comment when I saw your edit and thought "this made the question into something else". I have incorporated some of your edits.

Comment: @klutt No problem. I did wonder why the rollback but it is still your question... Happy to see you agree. I also tend to compare and check for duplicated answers in the low quality queue so it seemed relevant as well

Comment: The split view should be configurable/selectable by the user. If I'm on a landscape (wide) monitor I'd prefer side-by-side, but if I'm on a rotated (portrait) orientation over/under would be better. But currently, if I'm on a desktop landscape view, the inefficient usage of horizontal space in the UI means I have about 1/3 of my screen empty. So even with the split possible I'd likely open a second tab/window to use more of my available screen.